# Magento Fedex error authorization

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, fedex

We bought extension from WebShopApps for Address Validation. When customer change address on checkout extension send request to Fedex for validation address. It take all accesses from Fedex section. This access work fine for getting shipping rates, but when WebShopApps send request for address validation it get this response:

```
"[Message] => Authentication Failed"
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried contacting @WebShopApps? They have a pretty active Twitter account.

Answer (score 1):

I had several FedEx nightmares on a recent site.

The [Message] => Authentication Failed error always came down to one of two things:

- One of the numbers is wrong. We needed 4 numbers for proper API communication - api key, api password, account number and meter number. If any of those is wrong you will be refused.
- FedEx issues different credentials depending on the use. We had different credentials for our testing servers and production servers. I would make sure you are using the credentials you have in the proper context.

While this isn't a fix, I would wager that your issue lies with one (or both!) of the above.

Good Luck!

Comment: i gave all details correct, but not working

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your Fedex credentials or serial key for Address Validation is not correct. Can you disable the extension and get in touch with WebShopApps, we'll rectify. You'll need to email our support team.

Answer (score 0):

in my localsystem my case was worked successfully. In my server getting auth/bad request how can i solve this. My role and OAuth permission it was correctly gave all resources and permissions.

Comment: Is it solved your problem ?